# Refresh access token express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express server that gets a list of podcasts, from an endpoint.

This apart works fine, but there is a token that I use in requests to authorize entry to the endpoints.

the response when gaining an access token looks like:

```
{ access_token: '8c9d31761cbd32da25f1f1b988b527cde01c9d8a',
  expires_in: 604800,
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  scope: 'podcast_read episode_read podcast_update episode_publish' }
```

I have a refresh token that I use when refreshing the token and works well.

The way I'm doing it at the moment is, I have a text file that holds the token, the app reads from this when making a request, I have set up a function, that is called every time the podcasts route is called `router.get('/podcasts', checkIfTokenValid, (req, res, next) => {` to check if the token is valid or expired if so, refresh the token and write the new token to the file.

The only thing about this is; the write to file function is executed after the podcasts route connects to the endpoint, so the old access token is used.

Logging to the console, the functions are executed before the podcasts route gets all the podcasts, except for the writeAccessTokenToFile() function.

Just wondering, is there a better way to do this?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
var refreshToken = '425153ed4ddb4aee5sjsjsfaeffc46ab9944aece0400f';
var clientId = 'myId';
var client_secret = 'secret';
var isAccessTokenValid;
var access_token_file = path.join(__dirname, 'access_token.txt');

function refreshAccessToken() {
  console.log('refreshAccessToken')
  var body = { 'grant_type': 'refresh_token', 'refresh_token': refreshToken }
  var options = {
    url: `https://api.podbean.com/v1/oauth/token`,
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(clientId + ":" + client_secret).toString('base64') },
    json: body
  }
  request.post(options, (err, response, body) => {
    // console.log(body.expires_in*1000)
    if (err) {
      return response.status(500).json({
        title: 'An error has occured',
        error: err
      })
    }
    console.log(body)
    writeAccessTokenToFile(body.access_token);
  })
}

function getAccessToken() {
 return fs.readFileSync(access_token_file, 'utf8');
}

function writeAccessTokenToFile(token) {
  console.log('writeAccessTokenToFile = '+ token)
  var data = getAccessToken();
  var result = data.replace(data, token);
  fs.writeFileSync(access_token_file, result, 'utf8');

}

function checkIfTokenValid (req, res, next) {
  console.log('checkIfTokenValid')
  var options = {
    url: `https://api.podbean.com/v1/oauth/debugToken?access_token=${getAccessToken()}`,
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + new Buffer(clientId + ":" + client_secret).toString('base64') }
  }
  request(options, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        title: 'An error has occured',
        error: err
      })
    }
    // console.log(JSON.parse(body))
    isAccessTokenValid = JSON.parse(body).is_valid;
    if (isAccessTokenValid) {
      refreshAccessToken();
    }
     next();
  })

};


router.get('/podcasts', checkIfTokenValid, (req, res, next) => {

  var options = {
    url: `https://api.podbean.com/v1/podcasts?access_token=${getAccessToken()}`
  }

  request(options, (err, response, body) => {

    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        title: 'An error has occured',
        error: err
      })
    }
    res.json(JSON.parse(body));

    next();
  })

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: not sure i would essentially __cache__ a token on server side. acquiring a token is something that is done between a client and auth service. ensuring a token is valid is something server would do...but the client would send the token in every request.

Comment: I really feel that all this could be handled server side, as there's no loggin, so no need for client to send to sever, I want the access token to refesh automatically and not lock out users